is there any better way to use the fp or the fpu libraries to increase the accuracy in tikz math?
Here is one method.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \eval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
    \x2 = \eval{240*(5100+240)/7};
}

\x2

\end{document}


why don't you just use \fpeval{} in this case?

\fpeval{} can't use '=' sign to assign a variable and variable can't include integers.

how are you using this exactly? if you're using it in tikz, for example, what makes sense is likely to be rather different that what makes sense in some other contexts. tikz provides a floating point library of its own (but I would expect it is slower).

How precise do you need the result to be? Would the tikz fpu library be accurate enough?

I wrote an entire package about defining functions to be used inside of pgfmath which internally use l3fp: pgfmath-xfp. So if you need a function repeatedly that should use l3fp you can use that.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  needn't to be accurate enough . Only if avoid such an error :  "! Dimension too large."

Though \fpeval can't directly assign you could just use \tikzmath{\x2=\fpeval{240*(5100+240)/7};} no need to define \eval.

@Skillmon  You're right !

You've been told several times that TeX doesn't really work this way in terms of macro definition - what's the reason for not adopting a more standard interface?

since I have many things to calculate and tried a lot of softwares. At first , I use python . Now I want to use Latex for its beautiful pdf files.

@XCN That doesn't need you to use a non-standard interface

One thing I do when I need either high accuracy in, or lots of, computations is I use Python to write the TeX file, and write the outputs of its math expressions directly to the file. This speeds thingsup significantly, and will out-perform anything LaTeX can do math-wise.

did you use any packages such as pylatex ?

@XCN What I do is I open a .tex file in python, then write f-strings to it based on a python for loop and python-based calculations. You don't need any packages for this. Python just writes and runs the file for you.

you say you want to try a different programming language, but you have no interest in learning how it differs conceptually. you want to change the syntax, but keep the underlying grammar the same. it is relatively trivial to make TeX do this just with \def or to do the same with l3 fp functions, but it is not at all a good idea. defining \x globally without checking whether you are overwriting something critical is not at all sensible. so, to answer your comment on my answer, yes, I could provide a wrapper. but that's really not a good approach.

@Jasper if I use python， I need pyluatex package.

@XCN, I don't mean running Python inside the .tex document, I mean writing the .tex document itself using a python script.

If the aim is just to avoid the ! Dimension too large. error, then you could use the tikz fpu library:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
    \x2 = 240*(5100+240)/7;
}

\x2

\end{document}


More accurate? bc shows 183085.71428571428571428571; with \fpeval we get 183085.7142857143; with PGF math the result is given as 1.8307e5 which is quite far from the true value.

@egreg Of course not accurate, that's why I first asked if they needed a precise solution or just want to avoid the error.

How to accurate and avoid the error. Only like this   \tikzmath{\x2=\fpeval{240*(5100+240)/7};} ?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The OP is known for asking vague questions, but “increase the accuracy” seems to be quite precise.

@egreg "needn't to be accurate enough ." sounds as if accuracy isn't necessary https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728713/is-there-any-better-way-to-use-the-fp-or-the-fpu-libraries-to-increase-the-accur/728717?noredirect=1#comment1814438_728713

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz So not only the OP's questions are vague, they also contradict themselves.

@egreg Given that their "answer" didn't even use tikz math, I'd tend to agree with your description of vague and contradicting :)
